# Check Other App Uses NDK / Support Library / Third Party Libs Or Not

Tags: java, android

I notice that there're certain apps which could scan your android phone and tell you which app is using what libs. For example:

Facebook is using Android NDK, Android Supporting Library, Google Cloud Messaging.

My guess is that they may have used APIs like **PackageManager**, **ApplicationInfo**, **ActivityInfo** etc etc.

But somehow I'm not sure which specific API they have used to get the results. Any idea how they did it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how get infromation whether the app uses 'Android Supporting Library', but for the rest... Take a look at [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html). Once you get reference of the manager, you can get info about installed apps:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> packages = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0);
for(PackageInfo package : packages){
    String[] permissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
    // knowing permission you can conclude, what does app uses: 
    // GCM - com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE is required
    // ...

    ApplicationInfo app = package.applicationInfo;
    String apth = app.nativeLibraryDir;
    // based on this information you can conclude whether app uses NDK
}
```